# populate inside populate in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to create a populate inside populate

My schemas look like

```
 //item schema        
 item {
      name : String,
      type : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'item_types' },
      box : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'box' }, 
   }
//box schema
box{
    name : String,
    department : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'departments' }],
    type : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'types' }]
    manufacturer : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'manufacturers' },
  }
//departments schema
 departments{
         name : String
  }

 //types schema
 types{
         name : String
  }
 //item_types schema
 item_types{
         name : String
  }
```

When I am calling

```
item 
    .find()
    .populate('type ', 'name')
    .populate('box ', 'name')
     .exec(function (err, item) {}
```

Its working perfect. But, when i am calling like this its not populating the data its just showing ids only

```
      item 
    .find()
    .populate('type ', 'name')
    .populate('box ', 'name')
    .populate('box.department ', 'name')
     .exec(function (err, item) {}
```

How this can be done?

Thanks in advance
Babji

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend the Mongoose plugin 'mongoose-deep-populate'. I use it in lots of projects and it takes care of this with ease.

Usage example and docs: https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate/blob/master/README.md